# Ui automator 2 vs Ui automator 1

Tags: android, c++, android-uiautomator

I am using Ui automator 1 to change some settings on my phone (Main purpose here is to change somethings from settings of phone) and then I'm performing some tasks on phone.  I'm doing this by creating a C++ executable which ultimately perform this task using windows command line in single execution.
 my Question is can I do this using Ui automator 2?

my C++ code :

```
system("adb start");
system("adb devices");

//create ui project build

system("C:\\Users\\v.sahu\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\tools\\android create uitest-project -n SendMessage -t 1 -p C:\\Users\\v.sahu\\workspace\\SendMessage");



system("dir");
SetCurrentDirectoryA("C:\\Users\\v.sahu\\workspace\\SendMessage");  //setting cureent directory 


system("ant build");


system("adb push C:\\Users\\v.sahu\\workspace\\SendMessage\\bin\\SendMessage.jar /data/local/tmp/");

system("adb shell uiautomator runtest /data/local/tmp/SendMessage.jar");  //–c blog.send.message.SendMessage
```

Comment: You can try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which allows you to create scripts to do what you need.